# account/register not found in django project

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am new to django and started with a basic. The problem is while following a tutorial I created an account app that has a register page. For some reason whenever I am trying to go to my register page, django tells me that it doesn't match any of the paths.

below is the given code:
accounts app url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('register', views.register, name="register")
 ]
```

accounts app's views

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def register(request):
    return render(request, 'register.html')
```

register.html is:

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Registeration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="register" method = "post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type= "text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name"><br>
        <input type= "text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name"><br>
        <input type= "text" name="username" placeholder="UserName"><br>
        <input type= "text" name="password1" placeholder="Password"><br>
        <input type= "text" name="password2" placeholder="Verify Password"><br>
        <input type= "submit">
    </form>
</head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
  ```
web_project urls.py
   ```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include('travello.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
]
urlpatterns = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
````

the error I am getting is given below:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register.html
Using the URLconf defined in web_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

[name='index']
admin/
accounts/ register [name='register']
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, accounts/register.html, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

P.s: I know this question has been asked before but I tried everything still unable to understand where I am making a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `/` to your URL

```
path('register/', views.register, name="register")
```

in `settings.py` make:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        ... 
    }
```

Comment: It is still showing the same error. This is written on the terminal window when I run the server. [25/Aug/2021 11:03:24] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 22356
Not Found: /accounts/register.html

Comment: What is the path of  `Template` ?

Comment: FirstProject inside this is the sequence (accounts, assets, env, media static templates, travello, venv, web_project....)

Comment: try to change `template` path, check my updated answer

Comment: This is already done. TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],

Answer (score 0):

All you have to paste in your code;

Import your paths.......

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('register/', views.register, name="register")
 ]
```

basically you can call the - 'register/' any thing you want but it is necessary when creating a file path that you add the slash in after creating your path name. This enables your URL to Identify the necessary path.